# Using a java class inside another class without it's java file being actually present

Tags: java, spring-boot, compilation, package

I am writing a backend where the users can write some code inside a pre-written class like so,

```
import java.utils.*;

public class SomeClass{
   public int fun(){
      // some code written by the user.
   }
}
```

**Note** : *This SomeClass has no .java file in my project and loaded using the String code. The value of string being the above code itself.*

I am creating this class object using `GroovyClassLoader` like so,

```
try (GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader()) {
      // code is a String. The value of this code string is the above code.
      Class<?> loadedClass = gcl.parseClass(code);
      Class<?> add = gcl.parseClass(addClass);
      // using this object
}
```

Now if I have another class or classes like so,

```
import java.utils.*;

public class Addition{
   public int add(int a, int b){
       return a+b;
   }
}
```

**Note**:*This is also not present as a .java file in my code base, it is present as a String variable as above.*

I can use the `GroovyClassLoader` to load both the class but how can is use this `Addition` class inside my `SomeClass` class, like this,

```
import java.utils.*;
// somehow importing Addition class

public class SomeClass{
   public int fun(){
      Addition addition = new Addition();
      return addition.add(2, 3);
   }
}
```

As clearly mentioned above none of these files are actually present as .java files in my project and thus there is no package for any of these classes, **so is there anyway in which `SomeClass` can import and use `Addition`. If not then is there anyway this can be achieved.**

**Note** : Another example of my problem can be some online coding sites like Leetcode for example, there we only write the main code *(in my case `SomeClass`)* and the boilerplate code *(like initialising the arrays, variable and taking input and output, in my case the `Addition` class)* is injected to my main code by LeetCode itself. So I want to achieve something like this.

Comment: I suppose this is what [CompilationUnit](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilationUnit.html) is for in GroovyCompiler.

Comment: Can you guide me a bit about how to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I have no prior knowledge of this, but try calling `addSource`, `compile` and `getClasses` on the compilation unit. Inside script, importing works roughly using same rules as in Java.